# If earth water were pure, would the atmosphere still produce lightning?

Tags: water, electrochemistry, lightning

Like the title says: If Earth’s water were composed of pure H2O molecules, without anything else dissolved in it, would the atmosphere still produce lightning? I remember that distilled water is not a conductor, this is why I’m wondering.

Comment: Evaporated pure water can still become ionized in the atmosphere. The sea water need not be a conductor for lightning to exist. But you do need a potential difference. This can be between regions in clouds, or between clouds and the ground, not necessarily the sea.

Comment: There are plenty of insulators that can generate and hold a static charge.  Example: rub a glass rod with silk or scuff your rubber soled shoes across carpet and then touch a door knob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lightning occurs *because* the atmosphere is an insulator. If the atmosphere were a conductor, then thunder clouds would not be able to accumulate a static charge: the charge would just travel back to the ground by conduction. There is some research which suggests that the details of paths taken by lightning bolts may be related to ionization channels in the air produced by cosmic rays. However, it doesn't change the basic fact that electricity is conducted between clouds and the ground when the insulating air breaks down under voltage and becomes conducting.

An amusing computation would be to reverse your question. Perhaps, if the ocean were made of pure water without any dissolved electrolyte, its conductivity might be poor enough that charges could accumulate until they were a static breakdown in the non-ionized water. There [are in fact measurements](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4994749) of the breakdown electric field in water, but I have not read them carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lightning can result.   The niceties of 'water' is
that it occurs in vapor, liquid, and ice phases in the
atmosphere.   The surface of ice is NOT exactly the same as
the bulk, however; it forms a hydroxide  ion layer, basically a surface charge.  That's part of why ice is slippery.

The next part is a bit tricky: updrafts and downdrafts, in addition to building up hailstones, can collide ice particles of different size.   Charge transfer in such a collision puts excess charge on the smaller of two particles, because of pointy parts of a solid being places for charge to pile up.

That mechanism can cause large amounts of
charge separation, and give rise to lightning.